# Check If Two Sets Are Equal - Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, set

```
;checks to see if two sets (represented as lists) are equal

(define (setsEqual? S1 S2)
(cond
 ( (null? (cdr S1)) (in_member S1 S2))
 ( (in_member (car S1) S2) (setsEqual? (cdr S1) S2))
 (else false)))

;checks for an element in the list
(define (in_member x list)
(cond
 ( (eq? x (car list)) true)
 ( (null? list) false)
 (else (in_member x (cdr list)))))
```

Can't seem to find a base case to get this working. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: added Homework tag, because it looks like it

Answer (score 3):

What is a set? (It's a list---okay, what is a list?) Here's a hint: there are two variants of "list": `'()` (aka `null`, aka `empty`) and those made with `cons`. Your function(s) should follow the structure of the data they consume. Yours don't.

I recommend reading [How to Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org) (text available online); it will teach you a "design recipe" for tackling problems like these. The rough outline is: describe your data semi-formally (that answers *what is a list?*), formulate examples and tests; use your description of the data to create a *template* for processing that kind of data; finally, fill in the template. The key thing is that the template is determined by the data definition. It's reusable, and filling in the template for a specific function can often be done in *seconds*---if you've created your template and examples correctly.

HtDP Chapter 9 talks about processing lists, specifically. That'll help with `in_member`. 
Chapter 17 talks about processing multiple complex arguments (eg, two lists at once). One more hint: if I were writing this function, I would make use of the following fact about sets: two sets are equal if each is a subset of the other.